# How to access all Set-Cookie values from Southbound in javascript

Tags: apigee

We have Set-Cookie values coming from our southbound, one of which we need to manipulate within the gateway before returning to the requester.

When I do the request via curl using -v, the format in the headers is:

`< Set-Cookie: COOKIE_ONE=-1%2C1; Path=/
< Set-Cookie: COOKIE_TWO=6tuDIqNZTQl%2FqbPXU0M13tcl0nM%3D%0A%3B2015-03-12+11%3A24%3A38.766_1426173878765-214752_1_-1002%2C-1%2CUSD_1; Expires=Sat, 11-Apr-15 15:24:38 GMT; Path=/`

When I try to access them within javascript using the context variable context.targetResponse.headers['Set-Cookie'], it only returns the first value. I have tried other variations as well as inspecting the value(s) of Set-Cookie within trace. I am able to get the specific one using a pattern in an extract variables policy, but I would like to have access to all of them so I can edit it and then send them along.

I know that using cookies and cookie manipulation are not really in the spirit of RESTful APIs, but this is the southbound we have to deal with and the requirements of the consumer.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a tremendous source of information and it is quite valued.  If your question is answered here, that is a very good thing.  Apigee has setup its own community site for all of its users.  You may consider posting your question there.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [this blog post](https://community.apigee.com/articles/2319/how-to-handle-multi-value-headers-in-javascript.html), which describes how to apply a workaround to implement what you're looking for. In essence, you need to concatenate all values from the list and then parse the string

```
var hdr = context.getVariable('response.header.set-cookie.values')+'';
// get the array of header values: 
var a = hdr.substring(1, hdr.length-1).split(',');
```

Hope it helps!